# PHP DOM Get Node Path from XML does not return tag names

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, kml

I am trying to search through a KML file (for those who don't know, it's an XML file containing GPS information for marking lines and polygons on a map), which has a layout as follows:

```
<kml xmlns="..." blah blah blah>
    <Document id="Layers">
        <name>Layers</name>
        <Snippet></Snippet>
        <description>Sample Location Data</description>
        <Folder id="Folder1">
            <name>The First Folder</name>
            <Snippet></Snippet>
            <description>Sample Folder</description>
            <Placemark id="ID_00000">
                <name>First Placemark</name>
                <Snippet></Snippet>
                <styleUrl>#PolyStyle00</styleUrl>
                <MultiGeometry>
                    <Polygon>
                        <extrude>0</extrude>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitude>
                        <tesselate>1</tesselate>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                            <LinearRing>
                                <coordinates>INSERT A TONNE OF GPS COORDINATES HERE</coordinates>
                            </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                    </Polygon>
                </MultiGeometry>
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

This is only sample data. The actual file is 15 MB. It also has many more folders, some of which are nested inside other folders.

What I am trying to do is get a list of all of the Placemark elements. My current code looks like so:

```
$data = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . './kmlFiles/lokations.kml');
$XML = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$document = $XML->Document;
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($document);
$placemarks = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Placemark');
$placemarksArr = array();
foreach($placemarks as $dirKey => $dirVal) {
    $placemarksArr[count($placemarksArr)] = $dirVal->getNodePath();
}
var_dump($placemarksArr);
```

This works. However, when I read through my var_dump, my first value is as follows:

```
[0]=> string(20) "/*/*/*[4]/*[4]"
```

The next Placemark for example, is nested inside a folder inside the second folder in the root "directory":

```
[1]=> string(19) "/*/*/*[5]/*[3]/*[4]"
```

It would make sense to me however, that the output I would expect should be:

```
/XML/Document/Folder/Placemark
```

or

```
/XML/Document/Folder[0]/Placemark[0]
```

Given that I have just shy of 10,000 Placemarks in this file, I would prefer a solution that does not involve me breaking up the path and finding the element type for every asterisk and then the appropriate instance of that element inside it's parent. My understanding was DOMNode:getNodePath() would return an xpath more readable to humans than their position in the parent.

Am I going about this wrong? Is there a better way to retrieve an array of paths to my Placemarks?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `/XML/Document/Folder/Placemark` would not be valid. The XML uses a namespace, so you need to register a prefix for it and use it in Xpath.

Something like `/kml:XML/kml:Document/kml:Folder/kml:Placemark`.

`DOMNode::getNodePath()` does not have a prefix to use, so it falls back to the `*` - it matches any element node.

You could use Xpath to find the necessary information about a node to build your own location path expression. For `ancestor::*` would fetch all parent elements up to the document node. `count(preceding-sibling::Placemark)` would count all `Placemark` nodes with the same parent node before the current one.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply!

Can I register a namespace to make /XML/Document/Folder/Placemark valid or is that not possible?

Also, from your reply, my understanding is that if I add a namespace with the kml prefix, then I would have to change all the tags so that Placemark, what I'm searching for, would change from <Placemark> to <kml:Placemark>

Is that correct? I'd prefer not to do that in my files as they may regularly update, but I guess I can do that in PHP. I will be caching the files to remove parts I don't need and to cut down run time for clients, so runtime isn't a huge issue.

Comment: No, Xpath 1.0 has no concept of a default namespace. Any namespace has to be referenced using a prefix. Well something like `*[local-name() = 'tag' and namespace-uri() = 'urn:namespace']` is possbile, but not useful for that. Additionally you can not register namespaces for DOM API use, only for Xpath expressions. I am not sure what you're trying to do with the location path anyway - you might want to rethink that concept.